# Много BAD секторов на HDD

Tags: hdd

Результат проверки CHKDSK:

> ```
> 976760831 KB total disk space.
>    113728 KB in 5 files.
>         4 KB in 11 indexes.
>      1880 KB in bad sectors.
>     96015 KB in use by the system.
>     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
> 976549204 KB available on disk.
> ```

Можно ли продолжать использовать такой HDD? Или как его можно спасти?

Comment: Проверьте диск [MHDD](http://www.ihdd.ru/mhdd) или [Victoria](http://www.ihdd.ru/victoria) тогда будет понятно. На скрине, я так понимаю, вывод `chkdsk`?

Comment: Да, для начала опубликуйте в вопросе информацию SMART очень интересует количество нестабильных и переназначенных секторов. Хотя если вам chkdsk начал давать беды, боюсь области под переназначение уже кончились

Comment: Данные в КБ, но сильно подозреваю, что chkdsk считает весь ntfs-кластер, если в нём находится даже один бэд-блок. Так что реально бэд-блоков может быть около 30. Посмотри нормальной программой, хотя бы Speccy.

Comment: Как только появились бэд-сектора на жёстком диске, следует **немедленно** покупать новый и спасать со старого всю информацию, которую удастся достать. Появление бэд-секторов означает, что диск может умереть окончательно от любого чиха.

Comment: Не забывайте о том, что бэд-блоки могут быть софтовыми - из-за нарушения логики диска, а не физики. CHKDSK - ни о чём. Проверяйте Victoriа'ей с опцией Remap. Потом смотрите в S.M.A.R.T. параметр 05.

Answer (score 2):

Последите за тенденцией роста количества плохих секторов. Если их количество будет расти, то лучше такой хард сразу выкинуть, чтобы не сталкиваться с непонятными глюками и пропаданием/порчей данных на диске в будущем. Если количество расти не будет, то можно, как уже советовали, пометить эти сектора с помощью специальной программы. Мне тоже нравится Victoria.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую проверить ваш диск программой [victoria](http://www.mhdd.ru/programs/victoria-hdd.html), из под DOS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выставляете *Remap*, как на скриншоте и начинайте проверку. Если программа найдёт bad сектора, она пометит их и при работе они больше не будут использоваться. А на диск можно будет поставить систему.

Answer (score -1):

Я согласен с автором комментария, предлагающем избавится от диска на котором появились плохие сектора. Плохие сектора - это компрометация устройства и всегда путь к потере данных в будущем.

Накопители нынче стоят относительно недорого и терабайтный диск как у вас вполне можно купить за 50-60 долл. если хорошо поискать.

Да, это вынужденные инвестиции, но они того стоят в сравнении с головными болями от потери данных.